# Как открыть приложение по нажатие на ссылку?

Tags: android

Как называется метод чтобы при нажатии на ссылку открывалось приложение на android, а не браузер или что-то другое??

Answer (score 1):

> В недавно выпущенной версии `Android Marshmallow (6.0)` появился новый
>   механизм непосредственного открытия приложений — ссылки приложений.
>
> Этот механизм воспроизводит функциональность универсальных ссылок в
>   iOS 9, где при переходе по обычной ссылке `HTTP/HTTPS` немедленно
>   открывается соответствующее приложение, если оно установлено.
>
> Вот логика переадресации в ссылках приложений.
>
> - Открыть приложение с намерением, если оно установлено.
> - Вернуться к веб-ссылке, если приложение не установлено.

[(Источник.)](https://blog.branch.io/ru/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%81/)

Также ссылка на официальную документацию, где рассказывается про **`deep linking`** android developer [туть.](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

**p.s.** *Маленький комментарий, искал нечто подобное, но также заметил что для работы этого функционала, приложение необходимо подписать. (поправьте,
 если я не прав. Спасибо)*

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/265580)

Comment: @Темкатоже спасибо за замечание, сейчас исправлю.